# In Tab Navigator how to remove the pause when navigate to second tab

Tags: react-native

I am using the tab navigator in stack navigator ..when in tab navigator i move to next tab there a little bit pause then move to next tab...the code of index file is

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { AppRegistry,Alert,ScrollView, Image, Dimensions, 
Text,View,TouchableOpacity,StyleSheet} from 'react-native'
import Login from './login'
import SignUp from './signup'
import forget from './forget'
import Tabo from './DefaultTabBar'
import { StackNavigator,TabNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
import HomeButton from './HomeButton'
import ProfileScreen from './ProfileScreen'
import Granjur from './granjur'
const background=require("./flag/1.jpg");

export default class TabViewExample extends Component {
render(){
const { navigation } = this.props;
return(

    <App navigation={ navigation }/>

);
}
}
const MyApp = TabNavigator({
  Home: {
    screen: HomeButton,
  },
  Notifications: {
    screen: ProfileScreen,
  },

},

 {
   swipeEnabled:false,
   initialRouteName: 'Home',

  tabBarOptions: {
    activeTintColor: '#e91e63',
  },
});

const Simple = StackNavigator({
  Login: {
    screen: Login,
  },
  signup: {
    screen: SignUp,
  },
  forget:{
    screen:forget
  },
  dashbord:{
    screen:Granjur
  }
});
AppRegistry.registerComponent('TabNavigator', () => Simple);
```

i also use scrollable tabView in that tab view also that problem occur..In second tab i have a swipable list view may be due to this error come how i resolv this the code for profile screen is that

```
import React, {
    Component,
} from 'react';
import {
    AppRegistry,
    ListView,
    StyleSheet,
    Text,
    TouchableOpacity,
    TouchableHighlight,
    View,
    Alert,
    Dimensions
} from 'react-native';

import { SwipeListView, SwipeRow } from 'react-native-swipe-list-view';
var alertMessage="You want to Delete it";
var alertMessage1='why press it'
var v1=1.0;
const wid=Dimensions.get('window').width;
export default class App extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.ds = new ListView.DataSource({rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2});
        this.state = {
            basic: true,
            listViewData: Array(5).fill('').map((_,i)=>`item #${i}`)
        };
    }
    deleteRow(secId, rowId, rowMap) {
        rowMap[`${secId}${rowId}`].closeRow();
        const newData = [...this.state.listViewData];
        newData.splice(rowId, 1);
        this.setState({listViewData: newData});
    }

    // undoRow(rowId) {
    //  const newData = [...this.state.listViewData];
    //  this.setState({listViewData: newData});
    //  this.setState({listViewData: newData});
    // }
    render() {
        return (

                    <SwipeListView
                        dataSource={this.ds.cloneWithRows(this.state.listViewData)}
                        renderRow={ data => (

                            <TouchableHighlight
                                onPress={ _ => Alert.alert(
            'Alert Title',
            alertMessage1,
          ) }
                                style={styles.rowFront}
                                underlayColor={'#AAA'}
                            >
                                    <Text>I am {data} in a SwipeListView</Text> 
                            </TouchableHighlight>
                        )}

                        renderHiddenRow={ (data, secId, rowId, rowMap) => (
                            <View style={styles.rowBack}>   

                                <TouchableOpacity style={{backgroundColor:'#2c3e50',alignItems: 'center',bottom: 0,justifyContent: 'center',position: 'absolute',top: 0,width: 75}} 
                                onPress={ _ =>  rowMap[ `${secId}${rowId}` ].closeRow() }   >
                                    <Text style={styles.backTextWhite}>Undo</Text>
                                </TouchableOpacity>

                                <TouchableOpacity style={[styles.backRightBtn, styles.backRightBtnRight]} 
                                    onPress={ _ => Alert.alert(
                                     'Are You Sure',alertMessage,
                                      [{text: 'OK', onPress: () =>this.deleteRow(secId, rowId, rowMap)},
                                        {text: 'Cancel',}]
          ) }>
                                    <Text style=

    {styles.backTextWhite}>Delete</Text>
                                    </TouchableOpacity>
                                </View>
                            )}
                            leftOpenValue={wid}
                            rightOpenValue={-wid}                       
                            disableLeftSwipe={true}

                        />
            );
        }
    }
    const styles = StyleSheet.create({
        container: {
            backgroundColor: 'white',
            flex: 1
        },
        standalone: {
            marginTop: 30,
            marginBottom: 30,
        },
        standaloneRowFront: {
            alignItems: 'center',
            backgroundColor: '#CCC',
            justifyContent: 'center',
            height: 50,
        },
        standaloneRowBack: {
            alignItems: 'center',
            backgroundColor: '#8BC645',
            flex: 1,
            flexDirection: 'row',
            justifyContent: 'space-between',
            padding: 15
        },
        backTextWhite: {
            color: '#FFF'
        },
        rowFront: {
            alignItems: 'center',
            backgroundColor: '#CCC',
            borderBottomColor: 'black',
            borderBottomWidth: 1,
            justifyContent: 'center',
            height: 50,
        },
        rowBack: {
            alignItems: 'center',
            backgroundColor: '#DDD',
            flex: 1,
            flexDirection: 'row',
            //justifyContent: 'space-between',
            paddingLeft: 15,
        },
        backRightBtn: {
            alignItems: 'center',
            bottom: 0,
            justifyContent: 'center',
            position: 'absolute',
            top: 0,
            width: 75
        },
        backRightBtnLeft: {
            backgroundColor: 'blue',
            //right: 75
        },
        backRightBtnRight: {
            backgroundColor: '#2c3e50',
            right: 0
        },
        controls: {
            alignItems: 'center',
            marginBottom: 30
        },
        switchContainer: {
            flexDirection: 'row',
            justifyContent: 'center',
            marginBottom: 5
        },
        switch: {
            alignItems: 'center',
            borderWidth: 1,
            borderColor: 'black',
            paddingVertical: 10,
            width: 100,
        }
    });

     App.navigationOptions = {
         title: 'Signup Screen',
        headerVisible:false  
     };

    AppRegistry.registerComponent('TabNavigator', () => App);
```

How i remove this pause plz tell me early as soon as possible..Thanks

Comment: It could just be your computer and connection, because the app is being built through a development server: it could be slowing down some aspects of the app. This is common in loading images also - i've got this annoyance in the project i am working on. Usually when you deploy the final app this delay is completely removed.

Comment: sir whwn i add a swipeable list then error come otherwise not

Comment: Yeah, your app components could be all simple, but the swipeable list could be slowing it down.

Comment: so what is the solution is there any kink of swipable list which can  not slow down....

Comment: i think this is the problem due to rerender when tab navigator rerender then it slow dow

Comment: i use react native tab view...But there is one problem i use  TabViewAnimated ... In this there no option of swipeEnable:Fasle...But i need to disable swip because if swipe enable then my swipable list not work